# Copy formula without change cell reference

Tags: vba, excel

I am copying columns of information based on a checkbox link being checked.  Everything works except a few rows that contain formulas.  I need to copy the actual formula or in other words I do not want the formula to change it's cell reference based on where it it copied to.  I tried adding a line to recopy the few lines with formulas, but can't get it to work.  (I added a comment in the code to show where I'm getting the error.)

In column A there is always text "EE Only" which I have defined as TextToFind.  The formulas that need to be copied will be starting in that row minus one and be 5 rows in total.  So if "EE Only" is in row 22 then I need to copy rows 21 through 25.

What I was trying to do here was to go ahead and use the code I had and then copy over the formula rows a second time with the actual formula.

```
    'Called from AddWorksheet
Sub CopyFinal(orgSheet As Worksheet, destSheet As Worksheet)

Const TextToFind As String = "EE Only"
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim RowNum As Range
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim J As Integer
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim benRow As Long

J = 2
lastColumn = 2
'Counts the number of benefits on each sheet.  Assumes that they will not go past row 40
benRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(orgSheet.Range("B3:B40"))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do Until IsEmpty(orgSheet.Cells(3, J))
Set RowNum = orgSheet.Range("A:A").Find(what:=TextToFind, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If orgSheet.Cells(80, J) = True Then
        orgSheet.Columns(1).Copy destSheet.Columns(1)
        orgSheet.Cells(3, J).Resize(benRow).Copy
        With destSheet.Cells(3, lastColumn)
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
            Range("A1").Select
        End With
        '**The line below is giving an error
        orgSheet.Cells(RowNum, J).Resize(4).Formula = destSheet.Cells(RowNum, lastColumn).Formula

    End If
    J = J + 1
    lastColumn = destSheet.UsedRange.Columns(destSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column + 1
Loop

orgSheet.Rows(1).Copy destSheet.Rows(1)
Range("D1").ColumnWidth = 26.14

Call AddShapes

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You define `TextToFind` as string then you substract `TextToFind - 1`. This is a type mismatch. I guess you wanted first to `Find` the text;something like `orgSheet.Colums(1).Find(TextToFind).Offset(- 1, 9).Resize(5)`. Not sure this will achieve your final goal but this part surely needs to be corrected.

Comment: I made some changes (updated original post).  I added Dim RowNum as Range and then tried to set it to be the text to find.  Now I'm getting an Type Mismatch error.  I checked and it's not finding the row number.  I am admittedly in over my head, but trying....

Comment: It should be `Cells(RowNum.Row, J)` :) . apart of that, why are you copying the formula from the `destSheet` into the `orgSheet` and not the other way?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the copying error.  It would have taken me forever to see that.  I made the change and it's "mostly" working.  It's copying the formulas but not in the right columns.  I also need to figure out the offset now too.  Thanks for heading me in the right direction.

Comment: I am now using this line in place of the line I indicated as giving an error.  I still need to have the formulas copied but starting one row up from RowNum and resize to 5 rows.  I know I need to use offset, but can not figure it out.  destSheet.Cells(RowNum.Row, lastColumn).Resize(4).Formula = orgSheet.Cells(RowNum.Row, J).Formula

Comment: `destSheet.Cells(RowNum.Row-1, lastColumn).Resize(5).Formula = orgSheet.Cells(RowNum.Row-1, J).Resize(5).Formula`

Comment: Thank you so much for the continued help.  So I had already tried that and it works for the first line, but when resizing the other four lines it uses the first formula (-1) and then using cell referencing copies it down.  The other formulas are different than the first line.  I was able to get it to work but had to use the line of code you gave me five times and changed the number in [RowNum.Row - 1] for each line.  -1, nothing, +1, +2, and +3.  So it's working, but any comments on a better way.  Like I said previously, I'm in over my head on this so anything I can learn would be great.